# Reverse an array exercise...solution works but mine doesn't. Why?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I'm working through this book "The C# Player's Guide" and got to the "Try It Out!" section in the chapter on arrays.

The instructions are as follows:

"Create 3 methods: one to create the array, one to reverse the array, and one to print the array at the end. Your main method will look something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        int[] numbers = GenerateNumbers();
        Reverse(numbers);
        PrintNumbers(numbers);
}
```

The `GenerateNumbers` method should return an array of 10 numbers.

The `PrintNumbers` method should simply use a for or foreach loop to go down the array, one at a time, and print out the items in it.

The `Reverse` method will be the hardest. Give it a try and see what you can make happen. If you get stuck, here are a couple hints:

Hint 1: To swap 2 values, you will need to place the value of one variable in a temporary location to make the swap:

```
//Swapping a and b.
int a = 3;
int b = 5;

int temp = a;
int a = b;
int b = temp;
```

Hint 2: Getting the right indices to swap can be a challenge. Use a for loop, starting at 0 and going up to the length of the array / 2. The number you use in the for loop will be the index of the first number to swap, and the other one will be the length of the array minus the index minus 1. This is to account for the fact that the array is 0-based. So basically, you'll be swapping array[index] with array[arrayLength - index - 1]."

With all that said, here's my code thus far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        int[] numbers = GenerateNumbers();
        Reverse(numbers);
        PrintNumbers(numbers);
}

// Generates array of numbers and returns array
static int[] GenerateNumbers()
{
        int[] numbers = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        return numbers;
}

// Reverses array to print backwards from 10 to 1
static void Reverse(int[] numbers)
{
        for (int index = 0; index < numbers.Length; index++)
        {
            //swapping array indexes
            int a = numbers[index];
            int b = numbers.Length - index - 1;

            //temp array temporarily holds value while swapping indexes
            int temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }
}

// Prints numbers in array after order has been reversed
static void PrintNumbers(int[] numbers)
{
        for (int index = 0; index < numbers.Length; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[index]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Again my code continues to print the array in numerical order instead of reverse. Here's the solution for the reverse method from the book:

```
static void Reverse(int[] numbers)
    {
        // Initialize one index at the start of the array, and another
        // at the end of the array. The index of the last item in the
        // array is the length of the array - 1.
        int firstIndex = 0;
        int secondIndex = numbers.Length - 1;

        while (firstIndex < secondIndex)
        {
            // To swap two numbers, we need to copy one value out
            // to a safe place so that it doesn't get overwritten.
            int temp = numbers[firstIndex];
            numbers[firstIndex] = numbers[secondIndex];
            numbers[secondIndex] = temp;

            // Move on to the next pair.
            firstIndex++;
            secondIndex--;
        }
    }
```

What's weird is they use a while loop instead of a for loop as the instructions state.

Can someone please help me understand where my code is going wrong and/or how I can translate their while statement to work as my for loop?

Comment: You are swapping a and b but not putting them back in the array....

Comment: Such mysteries are easily solved using the **[AWESOME Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** that comes with Visual Studio

Comment: Also `a` is a value from your array but `b` is just the index of the other value.

Comment: Aside from the code corrections in the answer given below, watch what your `for` loop does at every step. Try figuring out at which condition the `while` loop in the correct solution ends, and compare this with the condition at which your `for` loop ends. If you have difficulties, exercise your code yourself like being a computer (yes, you be the computer executing slavishly the code). Use a couple objects on your desk and put them in a line (that's your array). Keep track of the `index` variable (either on paper or your mind) and execute slavishly your code. You will see what will happen ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo I actually did just that haha...and then I duplicated the example given for reversing the order from the instructions using the array in a separate file to see they were reversing properly. However it isn't applying the changes back to the array. And I'm not entirely sure how to do that.

Comment: By the way, +1 from me for the effort put into the question. Nicely structured and relevant code included to understand your problem. Well done, if i may say so!

Answer (score 4):

In your code here:

```
int a = numbers[index];
        int b = numbers.Length - index - 1;

        //temp array temporarily holds value while swapping indexes
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
```

You are putting the number itself into a, while putting the last index into b (not the number at last index). It should be like:

```
        int tmp = numbers[index];
        numbers[index] = numbers[numbers.Length - index - 1];
        numbers[numbers.Length - index - 1] = tmp;
    }
```

And also your for loop must iterate through the half of the array as going further, would again swap them to their original place:

```
for(int i=0;i<number.Length/2; i++)
{
     int tmp = numbers[index];
     numbers[index] = numbers[numbers.Length - index - 1];
     numbers[numbers.Length - index - 1] = tmp;
}
```

If you assign them to `a` and `b` then you should put them back (`numbers[numbers.Length-index-1]=a; numbers[index]=b;`) as when assigning them, the value from array is copied to `a` and `b`, not the reference (address of them in memory)

Comment: Watch the `for` loop :-) OP's code doesn't stop iterating when reaching center of the array, but iterates until the very end of the array, essentially swapping back the swapped elements (assuming your code corrections are applied)

Comment: @Tonyobyo and after swapping them, you should put them back to the array (or as I did just swap the original ones)

Comment: @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani so as our orders are the same (and I initially had brackets around the value of int b as you added:

b = numbers[numbers.Length - index - 1];

It reversed the array when I tested it separately...so yes I need to add them back to the array. But I don't know how to go about doing that once they're swapped.

would I return numbers?

Comment: @Tonyobyo, there was another problem in your code, thanks to elgonzo. I edited my answer please see the last part of the answer.

Comment: @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani ah I'm sorry about missing the "/2"...that was also initially in my program but was messing around with all of it trying to figure it out earlier and forgot to change it back. So with all that said, it seems the last thing to do is to add it back into the array...just need to figure out how to do that

Comment: @Tonyobyo, the code provided in the answer here will swap the elements in the array. Not sure what you still need to figure out...

Comment: @elgonzo sorry I wasn't understanding why using the actual values as opposed to assigning them to int a and int b made a difference...so was it that by using "a" and "b" to hold values that it wasn't sending it bback to the array?

Comment: @Tonyobyo yes, if you assign them to `a` and `b` then you should put them back (`numbers[numbers.Length-index-1]=a; numbers[index]=b;1`); as when assigning them, the value from array is copied to `a` and `b`, not the reference (address of them in memory).

Comment: @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani I see. Not sure why that didn't click in the first place. Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

If I was going to reverse an array, I'd do it like this, as I think it's simpler and cleaner:

```
//new array to hold reverse 
int[] rev = new int[fwd.Length];
//establish an indexer variable for fwd and reverse
//variable f starts at 0 and goes to length -1
//variable r goes the other way
for(int f = 0, r = rev.Length - 1; f < fwd.Length; f++, r--)
  rev[r] = fwd[f];

return rev;
```

I appreciate your algorithm, swapping early entries with later entries, working back to half way along the array, but it's quite math and variable assignment heavy and seems to have caused confusion between e.g. "the array value at position 2" and "calculating the corresponding position to position 2"

I personally think it's simpler the declare another same size array and copy things into it, working backwards as you read the source array forwards - this approach might have been more flaw free when implemented.

Often one must consider readability, understandability and maintainability of code as well as other factors. Always strive to write code that is simple and self explanatory, even at the absolute cost of performance. The microseconds gained by optimsiing some tiny bit of code are easily lost into hours or days when scratching your head and saying "why doesn't this complex spaghetti *work?*" or even worse, for someone else looking at code and saying "what is this supposed to do, and why doesn't it work?"

You additionally asked how their while loop would translate as your for loop. Here is a for loop:

```
for(setup; test; post-loop-actions)
```

In their code:

```
static void Reverse(int[] numbers)
{
    // setup
    int firstIndex = 0;
    int secondIndex = numbers.Length - 1;

    // test
    while (firstIndex < secondIndex)
    {
        //post-loop-actions
        firstIndex++;
        secondIndex--;
    }
}
```

Hence their while loop, translated into a for loop:

```
static void Reverse(int[] numbers)
{
    // setup
    for(
        int firstIndex = 0, secondIndex = numbers.Length - 1; //setup
        firstIndex < secondIndex;                             //test
        firstIndex++, secondIndex--                           //post-loop-actions
    )
    {
        ...

    }
}
```

I split the for loop curly bracketed part over 3 lines; if the variable names in thir while loop example were shorter it might have fit more nicely on on line

You can carry out multiple assignments in on for loop setup/post-loop-action, by separating the statements with a comma.

There's a practical difference between these two forms - in the while loop form the variables are declared outside the loop structure and will remain available to code after the loop has finished.

Comment: This is an exercise. If anyone needs this, `Array.Reverse` is already implemented, there is no need to implement it at all.

Comment: Sorry, i should have said "If I was going to reverse an array *as an academic exercise*" ..